# Fetching Pig Script Output in Java

Tags: java, shell, apache-pig

Can I *load the output of a pig script storing the output in a Pig storage in Java*?

The last line of the pig script I am referring to is something like -

```
STORE D INTO '$output' USING PigStorage();
```

I *want to import the relation in java for further processing and rendering in UI*.

If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. Use [Embedded Pig concept](http://wiki.apache.org/pig/EmbeddedPig), it provides PigServer which helps to run the pigscript in java program.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pig.PigServer;

public class WordCount {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      PigServer pigServer = new PigServer();
      try {
         pigServer.registerJar("/mylocation/tokenize.jar");
         runMyQuery(pigServer, "myinput.txt";
        } 
      catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }

   public static void runMyQuery(PigServer pigServer, String inputFile) throws IOException {        
       pigServer.registerQuery("A = load '" + inputFile + "' using TextLoader();");
       pigServer.registerQuery("B = foreach A generate flatten(tokenize($0));");
       pigServer.registerQuery("C = group B by $1;");
       pigServer.registerQuery("D = foreach C generate flatten(group), COUNT(B.$0);");

       pigServer.store("D", "myoutput");
   }
}
```

Here are the more examples : http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.pig.PigServer

Comment: Thanks for the reply .

I have two issues while i take this approach -
1. My jar are at some remote server, so the pig script runs in the remote server. When i try to register for the jars locally, I am unable to do that.
Same script  if i run from command prompt, runs fine.
2. I want to process the D . myoutput... how can i access it back in my main block??

Comment: 1. For passing remote location jar, you can refer http://massapi.com/source/github/93/75/937584214/test/org/apache/pig/test/TestPigServer.java.html#376 link to know the procedure,  2. To retrieve the output, call PigServer.openIterator() or PigServer.store().

Comment: I am sorry for my bad ! but i am really in early stages of learning and would need a little descriptive answer.

When I am trying to 
PigServer pig = new PigServer(ExecType.LOCAL);

I see in console - 
 executionengine.HExecutionEngine: Connecting to hadoop file system at: file:///

However, according to my understanding this should check at the remote server location.

Pls guide.